# SQL Server : how to prevent new index indexing existing data

Tags: sql-server, indexing

If I wish to create a new index against a SQL Server database, how do I prevent it from indexing existing data? i.e. only new data should be indexed with this. I am worried about index size.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you had a flag that showed old vs new data you could look at a filtered index and filter out the old data.

Comment: I am worried about index size as there is a lot of existing data and I don't need the index to apply to old data.

Comment: A [*Filtered  Index*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) ? - There really needs to be a compelling reason to do this imo.

Comment: If you don't want the index to apply to old data then by all means use a filtered index (assuming you have a column that defines 'old data')

Comment: Once data is in a table, how and when it got there is irrelevant, unless you make explicit provision for recording that metadata (by having a history table, or explicit columns, etc).

Comment: @RichBenner if you would care then to also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931553/is-there-any-disadvantage-to-using-a-filtered-index

Answer (score 3):

Use Filtered Indexes

> Filtered Index is a new feature in SQL SERVER 2008. Filtered Index is used to index a portion of rows in a table that means it applies filter on INDEX which improves query performance, reduce index maintenance costs, and reduce index storage costs compared with full-table indexes

```
 Ex: CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_Department
     ON HumanResources.Employee(EmployeeID)
     WHERE Title= 'Marketing Manager'
```

For More Info Please Refer below links: 
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/introduction-to-sql-server-filtered-indexes/
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/01/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-filtered-index-improve-performance-with-filtered-index/

Answer (score 1):

Use Filtered Indexes, indexing only the records since a date.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_NEW_SALES  
    ON SALES (SaleDate, SaleCostumerId)  
    WHERE SaleDate > '2016-11-1';
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx