# SQL Server : are there any side effects to using a filtered index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Are there any inherit side effects when using a filtered index? E.g. if you insert a million rows, will the index take longer to process etc compared to having the same index that is non-filtered?

Comment: Disadvantage compared to *what*? If you don't use a filtered index, what else would you use that may work better/worse (and for what scenarios), such that advantages and disadvantages can be compared?

Comment: A lot of these questions ultimately come down to one word: 'Depends'. The variety of environments and different situations make this nearly impossible to answer with accuracy. The way of getting this answer is getting a dev environment and testing both options and comparing the performance.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I meant "side-effect" rather than disadvantage. Updated title.

Comment: @RichBenner what type of environmental factors might this depend on?

Comment: But again, compared to *what*? Are we comparing it to the situation of not having an index at all? Or of having a non-filtered index on the same column(s)?

Comment: @StevenMarkFord storage speed, available memory, available CPU, network latency, sql server version, server settings etc

Comment: Check that Quoted Identifier is set to On for all stored procedures and applications that connect to the DB, else you'll get errors.

Comment: This is not a great question, however I will share this as food for thought.  https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/sql-plan/filtered-index-side-effect

Answer (score 1):

There is always a threshold.
Let's look on the edge case -

- If all the records pass the filter then we have wasted CPU for nothing.
- If None of the records pass the filter than we invested some CPU filtering out records but we saved CPU, IO and memory for all the inserts we didn't do.

Your case is somewhere between.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on "If None of the records pass the filter than we invested some CPU at the filtering but we saved CPU, IO and memory for all the inserts we didn't do."

Comment: suppose we have a filtered index with the condition `x>999` and we are inserting 1M records to the table but all `x` values are less than 999. In order to check for each record if x>999 we have to invest some CPU. However, since no record is passing the filter than we are not inserting any new data to the index structure therefore we don't need no invest any more resources as opposed to non filtered index that would have required some work at this point.